# "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" Error when trying to delete values in cells

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, invalid-argument

the segment of my code is as follows,

```
If Not Column2 = Empty Then
    Set Rg2 = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=Column2)
    If Not Rg2 Is Nothing Then
        Column2Width = Rg2.MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
        StartCol2Column = Rg2.Column
        EndCol2Column = StartCol2Column + Column2Width
    Else
        MsgBox Column2 & " not found in " & BalkanSheet.Name
    End If
    Else
    Worksheets("Graph").Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 10)).Value = ""
End If
```

When i try to run it i get an error with the line `Worksheets("Graph").Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 10)).Value = ""`, saying "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

The i value is a variable that is set earlier in the code. What i want the code to do is if the If statement is false (Else) then it will delete the values in the cells specified.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Worksheets("Graph").Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 10)).ClearContents`  Range only allows two arguments a start cell and an end cell.

Comment: Well that was simple, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with Worksheets("Graph")
    .Range(.Cells(i, 7), .Cells(i, 10)).ClearContents
end with
```

The idea is that the `.` is a way to refer the worksheet and that is needed, when you refer to cells.